# Why is it not possible to use the is operator to discern between bool and Nullable<bool>?

Tags: c#, types, boxing

I came across this and am curious as to why is it not possible to use the `is` operator to discern between `bool` and `Nullable<bool>`? Example;

```
void Main()
{
    bool theBool = false;
    Nullable<bool> theNullableBoolThatsFalse = false;
    Nullable<bool> theNullableBoolThatsNull = null;

    void WhatIsIt(object value)
    {
        if(value is bool)
            Console.WriteLine("    It's a bool!");
        if(value is Nullable<bool>)
            Console.WriteLine("    It's a Nullable<bool>!");
        if(value is null)
            Console.WriteLine("    It's a null!");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Considering theBool:");
    WhatIsIt(theBool);
    Console.WriteLine("Considering theNullableBoolThatsFalse:");
    WhatIsIt(theNullableBoolThatsFalse);
    Console.WriteLine("Considering theNullableBoolThatsNull:");
    WhatIsIt(theNullableBoolThatsNull);
}
```

Calling `Main()` gives;

```
Considering theBool:
    It's a bool!
    It's a Nullable<bool>!
Considering theNullableBoolThatsFalse:
    It's a bool!
    It's a Nullable<bool>!
Considering theNullableBoolThatsNull:
    It's a null!
```

I'd expect;

```
Considering theBool:
    It's a bool!
Considering theNullableBoolThatsFalse:
    It's a Nullable<bool>!
Considering theNullableBoolThatsNull:
    It's a null!
```

Why do both `bool` and `Nullable<bool>` match each other?

What have I tried;

- I've consulted the docs for `Nullable`, `is`, `switch` and pattern matching.
- I think this might be related to [unboxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) of the value when it's passed into the method?

I think it might be unique to `Nullable` because I don't run into the same problems for other generic types. For example;

```
void Main()
{
     bool theBool = false;
     List<bool> theListOfBool= new List<bool>();    

     void WhatIsIt(object value)
     {
         if(value is bool)
             Console.WriteLine("    It's a bool!");
         if(value is List<bool>)
             Console.WriteLine("    It's a List<bool>!");
     }

     Console.WriteLine("Considering theBool:");
     WhatIsIt(theBool);
     Console.WriteLine("Considering theListOfBool:");
     WhatIsIt(theListOfBool);
}
```

Gives;

```
Considering theBool:
    It's a bool!
Considering theListOfBool:
    It's a List<bool>
```

I'm not looking to solve a problem. Just interested as to why it works this way.

Answers so far suggest it's `implicit` and `explicit` conversions that cause this behaviour but I haven't been able to replicate with the following example;

```
class A
{
    public static implicit operator A(B value) => new A();
    public static explicit operator B(A value) => new B();
}

class B
{
    public static implicit operator A(B value) => new A();
    public static explicit operator B(A value) => new B();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new A();
    var b = new B();

    void WhatIsIt(object value)
    {
        if (value is A)
            Console.WriteLine("    It's a A!");
        if (value is B)
            Console.WriteLine("    It's a B!");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Considering a;");
    WhatIsIt(a);
    Console.WriteLine("Considering b;");
    WhatIsIt(b);
}
```

Gives;

```
Considering a;
    It's a A!
Considering b;
    It's a B!
```

The docs for `is` say:

> It only considers reference conversions, boxing conversions, and unboxing conversions; it does not consider user-defined conversions or conversions defined by a type's implicit and explicit operators. The following example generates warnings because the result of the conversion is known at compile-time. Note that the is expression for conversions from int to long and double return false, since these conversions are handled by the implicit operator.

Are reference conversions, boxing conversions, and unboxing conversions something the framework decides?

Comment: Sure, because `false` can safely be converted (via an implicit cast) to both `bool` and `bool?`. `null` on the other hand can only be converted to `boo?`, which is why `value is bool` returns false.

Comment: According to Microsoft boxing/unboxing is one thing, but when it comes to int and int? you just can't use "is" operator: "Don't use the is operator to determine whether an instance is of a nullable type."
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/how-to-identify-a-nullable-type

Comment: @PiotrWojsa, that makes sense! The reference source for `Nullable` also points at this in the declaration of `GetUnderlyingType`. If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason `bool` and `Nullable<bool>` behave the same when passed to your method is because whenever you box a `Nullable<T>` it doesn't actually box the nullable value, instead it unwraps the value of the nullable and boxes that.  If the nullable value is null then you end up with just `null`, rather than a boxed `Nullable<T>` where `HasValue` is `false`.

If you box a non-null value, it'll just box the `Value` of the `Nullable<T>`.  So from the perspective of `WhatIsIt`, the first two calls are *literally indistinguishable*, because *the exact same value is being passed in*.

That just leaves the question of why *both* `is` checks return `true`, even though what's passed in, in both cases, is a boxed boolean, and not a `Nullable<T>`.  That's answered by the C# language specs, section 7.10.10:

> If T is a nullable type, the result is true if D is the underlying type of T.

In this case this is considering `E is T` and `D` is defined earlier as a computed value of `E` where:

> If the type of E is a nullable type, D is the underlying type of that nullable type.

This means that the `is` operator is *specifically* defined as treating nullable types as being equivalent to their underlying types, regardless of how you mix and match the actual value being checked and the type you're checking with nullable values and that nullable's underlying type.

Answer (score 5):

The value `false` can safely be converted to both `bool` and `bool?` because there´s an implicit cast-operator between them.

`null` on the other hand can´t be converted to `bool`, which is why `null is bool` returns `false`.

The `is` operator does not (and can´t) care about how you *declared* the variable - if at all. It just indicates the type of the *value provided at runtime*. You could have also written this:

```
WhatIsIt(false)
```

How would you expect the method to behave here? It simply tries to convert the value to both types - which it can - and thus returns true for both.

Why it does not work this way for other generics is simply because there´s no implicit conversion between the most generic types and their type-argument. Thus the following does not work:

```
string myString = new List<string>();
```

Comment: Implicit conversions aren't considered for the `is` operator, according to its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is): `3 is double` returns `false` although the C# language defines an implicit conversion from `int` to `double`.

Comment: @Dirk Hmmm, interesting. Making me wonder how `is` is implemented.

Comment: I've edited the question to add an example with implicit and explicit declared.

Answer (score 2):

`Nullable<T>` class has [implicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit) and [explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit) operators implemented which are used in such cases out of the box, take a look at [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.op_implicit?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Nullable_1_op_Implicit_T__System_Nullable_T_)

Here is the excerpt from [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e):

```
[System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable]
public static implicit operator Nullable<T>(T value) {
    return new Nullable<T>(value);
}

[System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable]
public static explicit operator T(Nullable<T> value) {
    return value.Value;
}
```

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) for `is` say; _it does not consider user-defined conversions or conversions defined by a type's implicit and explicit operators_. I understand now that `is` is saying; _could I safely cast to this_ and not _were you declared with this type_.

Comment: I've edited the question to add an example with implicit and explicit declared.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare

```
Nullable<bool> theNullableBoolThatsFalse = false;
```

`theNullableBoolThatsFalse` can hold 'true','false' or 'null' similarly `theNullableBoolThatsNull` can hold boolean values and Null. And when you assign Null it compltely becomes null can't be any other type . It does not refer to any object.
[Furthe Information About Nullable](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-nullable-types)